# Sorting An Array Inside An Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary

Hello I have an array of this form which I am displaying on my meteor template.

```
var data = [{text_name:'My life', 
score: [{name : 'james',score: 10}, 
        {name : 'john',score : 40},  
        {name : 'Abu',score : 80}]},
        {text_name:'The game real', 
score: [{name : 'penny',score: 30} 
        {name : 'john',score : 20} , 
        {name : 'Abu',score : 30}] }]
```

I want to sort the `score` key which is an array of objects in descending order. Using the example data in the `text_name:'My life'` I want Abu scores to display first because he scored highest.

I have tried sorting by using the code found on this link [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects).

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Please fix so we know what you mean (is it `score:[...`?) Also, if you have tried, post what went wrong. *Also*, why is this tagged [tag:meteor]?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. A comma is missing after the first `score: 30}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is have each list sorted within itself.

So here's what you'd need to do:

```
// iterate over data
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  // sort the item's score
  item.score.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });
}
```

Comment: i was able to make it work by doing b.score.score - a.score.score. Thanks for your help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sort method:

Also note, that as the comments have mentioned that is not valid JS, I added the correct format in the example posted above.

[Working example](https://jsbin.com/zuhuqi/3/edit?js,console)

```
var d = data.map(function(d) {
  return d.score.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.score + b.score;
  });
});
```